# Rails - how do I create a hyperlink to a page for a single record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

How do you make `<%= post.name %>` a link to its own page?

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= post.name %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

similar what this code does, but without the string `'Show'`

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', post %></td>
```

what i always had in mind is like how php does it, you wrap it in

```
<a href="<?php phpcode() ?>">
```

how can i do similar result in ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
<%= link_to post.name, post_path(post) %>
```

or even easier:

```
<%= link_to post.name, post %>
```